# why the output of the following c programming is "one " can anyone explain?

Tags: loops, logical-operators, short-circuit-evaluation

`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int i=0;
    for(printf("one\n");i<3 && printf("");i++)
    {
        printf("Hi!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`

**AS we already know "shortcircuiting condition of logical and operator(&&)
while we solving the condition of for looping the concept used is just an logical operators
According to shortcircuting concept ,for i=0
i<3 condition is true && printf("")
so in this statement left part is true therefore, right side condition is not evaluated

Comment: "in this statement left part is true therefore right side condition **MUST BE** evaluated", since they would *both* need to be true. You're confusing `&&` (AND) with `||` (OR). --- Then the question becomes "what is the return value of `printf` and what boolean value is that considered to be?"

Answer (score 0):

Looking at a reference for [`printf()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) we see:

- On success, the total number of characters written is returned.

So, given `i<3 && printf("")`, the first time round `i` is 0, so `i<3` is true, then `printf("")` prints zero characters, which returns 0, which is false, so the expression becomes `true && false`, thus `false`, so the loop terminates.